# How do I convert .obj to .json format for 3D models?

Tags: python, json, three.js, collada, .obj

EDIT: Nevermind, the windows command prompt seems to be a bit easier to use. It worked.
I'm trying to use the [convert_ob_three.py](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/utils/exporters/obj/convert_obj_three.py) python script file to convert .obj files to .js format.

Heres what I did: 
 1. Exported google sketchup model as a .obj 
 2. Installed python version 2, which by the way is the version that's required for the converter.
 3. Tried running the script file and it closes instantly
 4. Tried putting "python convert_obj_three.py -i mesh.obj -o mesh.js" (without the quotes) in the python command line. Got an error concerning bad syntax.
5. Tried with a "$" in front. No luck.

What the heck!? Should I just give up on .js and try the collada loader?

Comment: Post the exact and complete error. Also you might want to link to the source of this script as I am sure no one knows what it is or does.

Comment: You need to post exact errors you got along with the .obj file or we can't help you.

Comment: @jdi added a link to the script he is talking about

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I interpret what you have tried, seems like you did all of those steps wrong by some means...

You can't simply double click a python script that expects to be run in a command line with args.

You can't run shell sytax from a python interactive interpreter line.

"$" has no meaning in a python shell

Most likely what you simply want to do (not knowing anything about this script) is to open a normal command shell and run: `python convert_obj_three.py -i mesh.obj -o mesh.js`

Comment: Ok it seems as if I need to go to the directory where the .obj files are located. How can I do that with python script?

Comment: Use the full path to the files. Drag and drop them onto your shell if that helps.

Comment: Or before executing the command, run something like `cd "/Users/yourusername/Documents/my3dfiles"`

Comment: @dbr: But then you also have to make sure you use a full path back to the python script.